# Selecting specific rows from datafrom based on column match in another datafram in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a question. Please help.
I have two dataframe. data1 and data2

data1 has following data

```
HHID..... blockid....serial_number...name
100............1............1.........xxx
100............2............2.........yyy
100............1............3.........zzz
200............1........... 1.........sss
200............1............2.........ddd
```

data2 is as below

```
HHID-.......serial....... hospital
100...........3...............Delhi
200...........2...............paris
```

Now,i want to select rows in data1 based on HHID and serial in data2. For eg, here, in data2, we can see a row with HHID 100 and serial 3. So, I want select only that row from data1 where HHID is 100 and serial is 3. Similarly for HHID 200 and serial 2. Also, when I select row from data1, I dont want any extra columns from data2. All I care about is if HHID and serial in data2 is matching in data1. If it does, then I need that complete row in data1. So the output should be as follows

```
HHID....blockid.....serial....name
100..... .....1........3......zzz
200...........1........2......ddd
```

Can somebody help?

Thank you

Comment: FYI Karna, I would recommend providing sample data like so, so that all of us can take your definition and use it without having to build it ourselves:  `data1 <- data.frame(HHID = c(100,100,100,200,200), blockid = c(1,2,1,1,1), serial_number = c(1,2,3,1,2), name = c('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz', 'sss', 'ddd'))`

Comment: Very sorry. New here. Will do so hereafter. I tried your code, but not getting any match. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I will add my data frame definitions to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a unique ID for each data frame like so:

```
#data frame definitions
data1 <- data.frame(HHID = c(100,100,100,200,200), blockid = c(1,2,1,1,1), serial_number = c(1,2,3,1,2), name = c('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz', 'sss', 'ddd'))
data2 <- data.frame(HHID = c(100,200), serial = c(3,2), hospital = c('Delphi', 'paris'))

#unique identifier
data1$unique <- paste(data1$HHID, data1$serial_number, sep = '')
data2$unique <- paste(data2$HHID, data2$serial, sep = '')
```

Then, you can use the subset function to isolate rows in `data1`, like so:

```
result <- subset(data1, unique %in% data2$unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

Here I recreate the data:

```
library(tidyverse) 

data1 <- read.table(text="HHID blockid serial_number name
100 1 1 xxx
100 2 2 yyy
100 1 3 zzz
200 1 1 sss
200 1 2 ddd", sep = " ", stringsAsFactors = F, header = T)

data2 <- read.table(text="HHID serial hospital
100 3 Delhi
200 2 paris", sep = " ", stringsAsFactors = F, header = T)
```

That's my suggestion

```
results <- data1 %>% 
  rename(serial=serial_number) %>% 
  right_join(data2, by=c("HHID", "serial")) %>%
  select(-hospital) # get rid of the hospital column

results
```

If you are not familiar with the tidyverse, you can execute every line step by step until the `%>%` to see the single steps. That's the output:

```
   HHID blockid serial name 
1  100       1      3  zzz    
2  200       1      2  ddd
```

Comment: How can I put these output into a new dataframe?

Comment: I added that into the code now. the dataframe is now called `results`